# Reverse and Add in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working on an algorithm in javascript that solves a "reverse and add" problem. I've worked it out in my head and it *should* work, but whenever I try to run it in JSFiddle it just becomes unresponsive. I think it may be in an infinite loop, but i'm not sure why. Here is the code:

**HTML**

```
<p id="test"></p>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var x = 124;
function reverse(n) {
    for(var r = 0; n; n = Math.floor(n / 10)) {
        r *= 10;
        r += n % 10;
    }
    return r;
}
while(x != reverse(x)) {
        x =+ reverse(x)
}
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = x
```

Comment: In the `while` loop you've got `=+` instead of `+=`. I'm not sure why you think you need the `while` loop at all instead of just `x = reverse(x);`. *edit* oh wait I see. But still, `=+` isn't a syntax error but it's definitely not the same as `+=`.

Comment: `x =+ reverse(x)` is equivalent to `x = +reverse(x)`. `+` with one argument is equivalent to `0 + Number(argument)`. So that's `x = 0 + Number(reverse(x))`. Since `x` is already a number, it's just `x = reverse(x)`.

Comment: You should cache the result of `reverse(x)` in a variable. You are repeating the same operations twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below keeps reversing the variable

```
while(x != reverse(x)) {
        x =+ reverse(x)
}
```

If you run `reverse(124)` you get `421`. If you run `reverse(421)` you get `124`. Now, let's see what happens:

Starting with `x = 124`, we enter the loop:

1. `x != reverse(x)`
   =>
   `124 != reverse(124)`
   =>
   `124 != 421`
   =>
   `true`
2. `x =+ reverse(x)`
   =>
   `x =+ reverse(124)`
   =>
   `x =+ 421`
   =>
   `x = 421`
3. `x != reverse(x)`
   =>
   `421 != reverse(421)`
   =>
   `421 != 124`
   =>
   `true`
4. `x =+ reverse(x)`
   =>
   `x =+ reverse(421)`
   =>
   `x =+ 124`
   =>
   `x = 124`

And back to step 1.

---

When you say that you are trying to solve the "reverse and add" problem, I understand that you want to actually *add*.

That is, `=+` is probably a typo, and what you want is `+=`. That will take `124` reverse it to `421` add it to get `545` and then it is no longer different than its reverse.  Similar to what [Thalaivar explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40060274/402022).

Instead code of the form `x =+ value` is doing a unary `+` on `value` and then it assigns that to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You should come out of your while loop, what is happening is you are reversing `"124"` and then adding it to `"421"` which results in `545`, the while loop is again carried forward to check if x != "545" and so on.

```
var x = 124;
function reverse(n) {
    for(var r = 0; n; n = Math.floor(n / 10)) {
        r *= 10;
        r += n % 10;
    }
    return r;
}
while(x != reverse(x)) {
  x = x + reverse(x);
  break;
}

console.log("x", x);
```

Answer (score 0):

`=+` is not an operator, `+=` is.

The reverse and add algorithm can be used to test for [Lychrel numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number). Using the right `+=` operator is not enough. If a number *is* a Lychrel number, the loop still will never end. In the snippet, 20 random numbers are tested for 'Lychrelness' *up to 25 iterations*. It uses a simplified reverse method and es6 (aka es2015).

```js
const test = document.querySelector('#test');
const reverse = (n, r) => n ? reverse(n / 10 | 0, (r | 0) * 10 + n % 10) : r;
const someRandomNumbers = Array.apply( null, {length: 20} )
           .map( () => Math.floor(99999 * Math.random()+1) );
const isLychrel = num => {
  let iterations = 0;
  let rev = 0;
  while (num !== rev && iterations < 25) {
    iterations += 1;
    num += rev;
    rev = reverse(num);
  }
  return `${iterations === 25 ? '*Maybe Lychrel' : num}`;
};

someRandomNumbers.forEach( 
  n => test.textContent += `${n} => ${isLychrel(n)}\n` 
);
```

```html
<pre id="test"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I see you have found the syntax bug, I think the way the solution is implemented made it difficult to spot. Reverse is also called multiple times.

If you need to reverse and add, I would prefer the simplest solution and a more declarative approach with simpler pieces, more semantic variable names, which would hopefully make reading the code easier and thus spotting silly bugs like this.

As an example:

```
function reverse(num, carry = 0) {
    const left_over = Math.floor(num / 10);
    const result = num % 10 + carry;
    if (left_over === 0) {
        return result;
    }
    else {
        return reverse(left_over, result * 10);
    }
}

document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = String(421 + reverse(421));
```